# Bucketing dates and checking if between date range in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe

How can I check what category a date falls into if it is between a the dates in the date field? I cannot use `merge_asof` as the work; `pandas` is only v0.18.

```
d = {'buckets': ['1D', '1W', '1M'], 'dates': ['03-05-2018', '10-05-2018', '03-06-2018']}
date_buckets = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


    buckets dates
0   1D  03-05-2018
1   1W  10-05-2018
2   1M  03-06-2018
```

So, for example, if given the date 07-05-2018, how can I return 1W? I would need to do this for hundreds of rows so would need to be efficient.

thanks,

Comment: So you want 3 buckets, one is `1D: (03-05-2018: 03-05-2018]` `1W: (03-05-2018 : 10-05-2018]` and  `1M: (10-05-2018 : 03-06-2018]`?

Comment: actually it would be loads of buckets up to about 30Y but yes, you get the idea. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way that could easily be extended to a larger set of dates to match:

```
scalar_date = pd.DataFrame(index=[pd.to_datetime("07-05-2018", format="%d-%m-%Y")])

scalar_date.join(date_buckets. \
                   set_index('dates'). \
                   reindex(pd.date_range(date_buckets.dates.min(), \
                                         date_buckets.dates.max()), \
                           method='bfill'))

#            buckets
# 2018-05-07      1W
```

The idea here is to resize your `date_buckets` dataframe (using `.reindex` with `method='bfill'`), so that you can easily join it to a dataframe with your lookup dates.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) for binning values:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'buckets': ['1D', '1W', '1M'],
     'dates': ['03-05-2018', '10-05-2018', '03-06-2018']}
df_bin = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df_bin['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df_bin['dates'], dayfirst=True)\
                    .dt.strftime('%Y%m%d').astype(int)

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['07-05-2018']})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True)\
               .dt.strftime('%Y%m%d').astype(int)

df['Tenor'] = pd.cut(df['date'],
                     bins=df_bin['dates'],
                     labels=df_bin['buckets'].iloc[1:])

print(df)

       date Tenor
0  20180507    1W
```